# Drawing gradient using CAGradientLayer on UIView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cagradientlayer

I'm trying to draw a gradient on the background view of a View Controller with but for some reason I couldn't get it to work.

Here is my method, which is called from `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)drawGradient
{
  CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
  gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;

  gradient.colors = @[[UIColor greenColor], [UIColor redColor]];
  gradient.locations = @[@0.0, @1.0];

  [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}
```

...but nothing happens, and the gradient doesn't appear. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `colors` awaits for a `NSArray` of `CGColorRef`, not `UIColor`, no ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to Larme's comment, I figured out my mistake.

Instead of

```
gradient.colors = @[[UIColor greenColor], [UIColor redColor]];
```

the right this is

```
gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
```

Because `gradient.colors` expects a `NSArray` of `CGColorRef`. The `(id)` cast is also needed in order to create the `NSArray`.